# Получить сумму значений ключей словаря, содержащихся в строке

Tags: python, словари, for

```
list_name1=[]
list_name2=[]

x = {'а':'1','б':'2','в':'3','г':'4','д':'5','е':'6','ё':'7','ж':'8','з':'9','и':'10','й':'11','к':'12','л':'13',
'м':'14','н':'15','о':'16','п':'17','р':'18','с':'19','т':'20','у':'21','ф':'22','х':'23','ц':'24','ч':'25',
'ш':'26','щ':'27','ъ':'28','ы':'29','ь':'30','э':'31','ю':'32','я':'33'}
name1 = input("имя: ")
for m in name1:
   if m in x.keys():
      print(x[m])
```

пробовал делать так, но потом понял, что это *ерунда

```
if m in x.keys():
      d = 0
      c = d + int(x[m])
      print(c)
```

Comment: Напишите подробнее. Добавьте пример и ожидаемый результат

Comment: `print(sum(int(x.get(c, '0')) for c in name1))`

Answer (score 1):

```
name1 = input("имя: ")
sum_of_name = 0
for m in name1:
   sum_of_name += int(x[m])
```

Answer (score 1):

Если в словаре значения сразу задать числами, а не строками содержащие числа, то подсчёт суммы делается в одну строчку.

```
x = {'а': 1,'б': 2,'в': 3,'г': 4,'д': 5,'е': 6,'ё': 7,'ж': 8,'з': 9,'и':10,'й':11,
     'к':12,'л':13,'м':14,'н':15,'о':16,'п':17,'р':18,'с':19,'т':20,'у':21,'ф':22,
     'х':23,'ц':24,'ч':25,'ш':26,'щ':27,'ъ':28,'ы':29,'ь':30,'э':31,'ю':32,'я':33}
name1 = input("имя: ")
print(sum(map(x.get, name1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

это делается в одну строку и без переделки словаря

```
print(sum(int(x.get(c, '0')) for c in name1))
```